# How can I use ghcid allow-eval with cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack, ghcid

I have a Stack based project and with the following:

`ghcid --command 'stack ghci' --allow-eval --clear --no-height-limit '-o ghcid.log'` I can have ghcid execute/evaluate a function as follows:

```hs
-- $> unit_simple_single
unit_simple_single :: IO ()
unit_simple_single = runTest 1 superSimplSuite
```

If I switch the project from Stack to Cabal and run:

`ghcid --command 'cabal repl' --allow-eval --clear --no-height-limit '-o ghcid.log'`

I get:

```
<interactive>:28:1-18: error:
    Variable not in scope: unit_simple_single
```

I understand that Stack does a lot of work introspecting modules in a project and loading them when you call `stack ghci` and `cabal repl` doesn't, so I guess I need to  create a `.ghci` file but I haven't been able to get this to work.

eg.

```
:load SuiteRuntimeTest
```

I still get the same result.

So what needs to go into `.ghci` to get `ghcid` eval working?
Is there a utility, like an "hpack for ghci", that could generate this file?

Answer (score 0):

Answer turned out to be pretty simple.

Just list all lib modules (`exposed-modules` and `extra-deps`) in the `:load (:l)` and `:module (:m)` property in the .ghci file

e.g.

`Myproject\.ghci` - a four module project

```
:l AuxFiles Check Common DSL 

:m AuxFiles Check Common DSL
```